# Dafny predicate neither true nor false

Tags: dafny

How can a Dafny predicate be neither true nor false?

This:

```
predicate sorted(s: seq<int>)
{
  forall j, k :: 0 <= j < k < |s| ==> s[j] <= s[k]
}

lemma SortedTest()
{
  assert  sorted([1, 3, 2]);
  assert !sorted([1, 3, 2]);
}
```

Produces double assertion violations:

```
Dafny program verifier version 1.9.7.30401, Copyright (c) 2003-2016, Microsoft.
Sort.dfy(8,10): Error: assertion violation
Sort.dfy(3,2): Related location
Sort.dfy(3,43): Related location
Execution trace:
    (0,0): anon0
Sort.dfy(9,9): Error: assertion violation
Execution trace:
    (0,0): anon0

Dafny program verifier finished with 2 verified, 2 errors
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dafny is not saying that the assertions are false, it is saying that it can't *prove* that they hold. If you give it a bit more help then it will prove the one that is true:

```
predicate sorted(s: seq<int>)
{
  forall j, k :: 0 <= j < k < |s| ==> s[j] <= s[k]
}

lemma SortedTest()
{
  var a := [1, 3, 2];
  assert a[0] == 1 && a[1] == 3 && a[2] == 2;
  assert  sorted(a);
  assert !sorted(a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a weird hint to have to give. :-)

Comment: It is to do with the way that the heap is encoded in Dafny. Essentially Dafny usually only automatically unrolls inductive definitions once. So it will usually only pick the most recently assigned element of the array to instantiate the quantifiers (i.e. the only element that was assigned in the _current_ heap) unless you do something (like the assertion I wrote) that causes the other relevant elements to be in the solvers e-graph for the current heap. In my experience, its actually better at dealing with formulas (arrays in general) than concrete values (a particular array).

Comment: Is there a way to tell the difference between "I can prove this is wrong" and "I can't prove this is right"?